# Using Jquery UI Slider with AMCharts 4 Pie Chart

Tags: jquery, amcharts, jquery-ui-slider, amcharts4

I can't seem to get the Jquery UI slider to work with an AMCharts 4 pie chart.  I'm doing something incorrectly with the slider function, but I'm not 100% sure what's causing the issue.

Ideally, I want to use the slider to cycle through several data sets in an array.  This concept works fine with a regular HTML range slider, but I think the Jquery route is a bit more extendable.  Has anyone else had success in implementing the Jquery UI slider with an AM Charts 4 pie chart?  Any pointers you'd like to share?  Greatly appreciate any insight!

```js
  

// Set theme
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart2 = am4core.create("chartdiv2", am4charts.PieChart);

var chart2Data = [
    // 50/40/10
    [
        { category: "U.S. Equities", value: 0.55},
        { category: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: 0.40},
        { category: "Hybrid Strategy", value: 0.07},
        ],
     // 40/40/20
        [
        { category: "U.S. Equities", value: .50},
        { category: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { category: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .14},
        
    ],
   // 30/40/30
    [
        { category: "U.S. Equities", value: .45},
        { category: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { category: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .21},
       
    ],
     // 20/40/40
    [
        { category: "U.S. Equities", value: .40},
        { category: "U.S. Fixed Incomed", value: .40},
        { category: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .28},
       
    ],
    // 10/40/50
    [
        { category: "U.S. Equities", value: .35},
        { category: "U.S. Fixed Income", value: .40},
        { category: "Hybrid Strategy", value: .35},
        
    ]
];

// Add data
chart2.data = chart2Data[0];

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart2.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "category";

// Let's cut a hole in our Pie chart the size of 40% the radius
chart2.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);

// Put a thick white border around each Slice
pieSeries.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color("#4a2abb");
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeWidth = 2;
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;


// Add a legend
chart2.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart2.legend.position = "right";

//Binds data to HTML range slider, carryover from AM Charts 3
function selectDataset(d) {
    chart2.data = chart2Data[d];
    chart2.validateData();
    chart2.animateAgain();
}

$( function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    value: 0,
    "create": function( event, ui ) {
          var dataSet = chart2Data[0];
          $("#slider .ui-slider-handle").text(dataSet.category);
        },
    slide: function( event, ui )  {
          var dataSet = chart2Data[ui.value];
          e.chart2.dataProvider = dataSet.value;
          e.chart2.validateData();
          $(ui.handle).text(dataSet.category);
        }
  });
} );

//Add exposure value to middle of chart
var label = pieSeries.createChild(am4core.Label);
label.text = "${values.value.sum}";
label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
label.verticalCenter = "middle";
label.fontSize = 40;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#slider {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 3.2em!important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -1.6em!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="4" value="0" name="dataset" step="0" list="ticks" onchange="selectDataset(this.value)">
 
<datalist id="ticks">
  <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</datalist>

 <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try setting up a working example? Edit your post and separate it into a runnable snippet (see the `JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet` option).

Comment: Good call.  Sorry about that.  Snippet has been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to make your current code work with jQuery's Slider, then the issue lies in your `slide` function option:

```
slide: function(event, ui)  {
    var dataSet = chart2Data[ui.value];

    // "e" doesn't exist here, and nor would changing it to "event" work
    e.chart2.dataProvider = dataSet.value;
    e.chart2.validateData();

    $(ui.handle).text(dataSet.category);
}
```

Change to the following:

```
slide: function(event, ui)  {
    var dataSet = chart2Data[ui.value];

    // same as the selectDataset() function for the regular HTML range slider
    chart2.data = dataSet;

    chart2.validateData();
    $(ui.handle).text(dataSet.category);
}
```

Working example:

```js
// Set theme
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart2 = am4core.create("chartdiv2", am4charts.PieChart);

var chart2Data = [
  // 50/40/10
  [{
      category: "U.S. Equities",
      value: 0.55
    },
    {
      category: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: 0.40
    },
    {
      category: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: 0.07
    },
  ],
  // 40/40/20
  [{
      category: "U.S. Equities",
      value: .50
    },
    {
      category: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: .40
    },
    {
      category: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: .14
    },

  ],
  // 30/40/30
  [{
      category: "U.S. Equities",
      value: .45
    },
    {
      category: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: .40
    },
    {
      category: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: .21
    },

  ],
  // 20/40/40
  [{
      category: "U.S. Equities",
      value: .40
    },
    {
      category: "U.S. Fixed Incomed",
      value: .40
    },
    {
      category: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: .28
    },

  ],
  // 10/40/50
  [{
      category: "U.S. Equities",
      value: .35
    },
    {
      category: "U.S. Fixed Income",
      value: .40
    },
    {
      category: "Hybrid Strategy",
      value: .35
    },

  ]
];

// Add data
chart2.data = chart2Data[0];

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart2.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "category";

// Let's cut a hole in our Pie chart the size of 40% the radius
chart2.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);

// Put a thick white border around each Slice
pieSeries.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color("#4a2abb");
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeWidth = 2;
pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;


// Add a legend
chart2.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart2.legend.position = "right";

$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,
    value: 0,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      var dataSet = chart2Data[0];
      $("#slider .ui-slider-handle").text(dataSet.category);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var dataSet = chart2Data[ui.value];
      chart2.data = dataSet;
      chart2.validateData();
      $(ui.handle).text(dataSet.category);
    }
  });
});

//Add exposure value to middle of chart
var label = pieSeries.createChild(am4core.Label);
label.text = "${values.value.sum}";
label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
label.verticalCenter = "middle";
label.fontSize = 40;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

#slider {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 3.2em!important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -1.6em!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="chartdiv2"></div>

  <datalist id="ticks">
  <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</datalist>

  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that there is no `validiateData` function in AmCharts4, so you'll want to remove that from your answer.. When replacing the entire data array, AmCharts4 will automatically refresh itself. If you're updating the array in place, you can use invalidateData and invalidateRawData. [Docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Dynamic_updates)

Comment: Thanks, although I was trying to keep edits to OP's code to a minimum. The `validateData` function was already there and didn't throw any errors, so I just left it.

Comment: This is awesome!  Thank you so much!  I figured it was something minor.  I'm sure this example will help others in the future.